# Meteor - Is it possible to query the database for items with a field that are equal or less than a value?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

In my Meteor app my items in the database have a createdOn field with a date object as the value. I'd like to query for all items that were created on or before a certain date.

Is there a way to match on items with a value equal or less than a value I provide? Or do I need to return all items and then loop through them and pick out the ones I need?

Comment: What do you mean by "all items"? added rows or new created object database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor uses [mongodb](http://mongodb.org) as its database so you can just do this with [the mongo operator $lt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/).

For example:

```
Posts.find({createdOn: {$lte: new Date()}});
```